# .NET VS- [WebException: The operation has timed out]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, webservice, wcf, webforms

Estoy desarrollando un programa en *C#* con *Web Forms* que consumen métodos de un servicio *WCF*.

Me está saliendo el siguiente error:

> Excepcion "The operation has timed out".
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto? Tal error no es de compilación.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente la excepcion "The operation has timed out" significa que el servidor ha agotado el tiempo máximo de espera a una operación, y tu programa no ha obtenido respuesta. Eso puede ocurrir porque la conexión es mala, o porque el servidor esta saturado, o porque la operación que quieres hacer requiere mucho proceso, o entra en bucles raros.

Aún así, revisa que lo que ocurra no sea que te este dando una excepcion en el webservice con los datos que le mandas.